# Show that $\phi:A_4\longrightarrow GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ is a irreducible representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Given the representation $\phi:A_4\longrightarrow GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ with:

$$\phi_{(123)}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1\\
 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\, \text{and} \,\, \phi_{(12)(34)}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & -1\\
 1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Show that the representation is irreducible.

---

with so few information about the whole elements of the representation and its character I came to the conclusion that the fastest way might be , by simply calculating all the $\phi_{(123)}$-invariant subspaces and all the $\phi_{(12)(34)}$-invariant subspaces and
see that there is no possible intersection hence no common invariant submodule which implies $\phi$ has to be irreducible no matter how the rest of the representation looks like. This worked fine, but is it the most elegant way given only the informations above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi$ was reducible, then there would be a $2$-dimensional subspace $T$ of $\Bbb R^3$ and a $1$-dimensional subspace $O$ which would be invariant with respect to the action $\phi$ and such that $\Bbb R^3=T\bigoplus O$. But then $O$ would be of the form $\Bbb Cv$, for some common eigenvector of the given matrices. However, there are no such eigenvectors: the $1$-dimensional invariant subspaces of the second matrix are $\Bbb C(a,b,a+b)$ (with $a,b\in\Bbb C$ and $a$ and $b$ aren't both $0$), and $\Bbb C(1,1,0)$, and neither $(a,b,a+b)$ nor $(1,1,0)$ is an eigenvector of the first matrix.

Comment: In order to know that a 3-dim representation of $A_4$ splits, if it does, into a 2-dim representation and a 1-dim rep I first would need to know that 3 x 1-dim rep arent possible, or? If I wouldnt know that I could compensate the lack of knowledge and finesse by calculating all eigenspaces of both matrices and see that there is no common invariant space for both matrices?

Comment: If you had $3$ $1$-dimensional representations $O_1$, $O_2$, and $O_3$, then just let $O=O_1$ and $T=O_2\bigoplus O_3$. Then $\dim O=1$, and $\dim T=2$.

Comment: oh of course :D thank you

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the value of the character on the conjugacy classes, eg. from your information we have $\chi (123)=\chi(132)=0$, $\chi(12)(34)=-1$, $\chi(1)=3$. So the inner product evaluates to $\frac{1 \times 3^2+3\times (-1)^2}{12}=1$ hence it is an irreducible representation.

Comment: Yeah this looks fast, but it requires me to know the number of conjugacy classes and how many elements are in each. Which I did not know.

Comment: That is correct, but as the conjugacy classes of $S_n$ are given by the cycle length decompositions and we know the conjugacy classes that split when restricted to $A_n$ it is not a very difficult thing. And to know the number of elements in a conjugacy class is an elementary combinatorial problem.

Comment: Upvoting this because IMO it requires less computations than José's answer.

Comment: totally fine, I upvoted both. But the answer of Jose hit my questions better. Because I only thought about Information without character tables and conjugacyclasses, which ofc makes the task easier.